# Record Twilio Call Record to a database as soon as call is received or made

Tags: twilio-api, twilio-php

I have Twilio Voice Call implemented using Twilio JS SDK and PHP. Currently, when I fetch call logs and recordings, it takes a long time. So, I am thinking to record the call logs and recording URL in a database, from where it should be much quicker.

What is the best time during the code execution to get details for the current call and write to the database?

After the dial to number/client, or after the call completes or just do a fetch at a regular interval (not preferred)?

Answer (score 2):

I think I would create the database entry when you first make/receive a call, on the first webhook to fetch TwiML.

Then, to add the recording URL you should update that database record when you receive the [recording status callback webhook](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/webhooks/voice-webhooks#recording-status-callbacks).

Comment: Thanks! When I set the status callback, Twilio will send the call information to that URL. What response do I need to send to the Twilio StatusCallback request so that it doesn't interfere with the call? I am using JS SDK with PHP for the voice functionality.

Comment: You can just return an empty response with 200 status. Also, status callback webhooks are asynchronous to the call, so responding with TwiML won't interfere with the call anyway.